# passing relative paths in maven Arguments

Tags: scala, maven, relative-path

i'm using scala code to write data into files , and i'm running the scala code with Maven using the launcer

```
<launcher>
  <id>GenerateLLMasterFile</id>
  <mainClass>org.dbpedia.extraction.scripts.LanguageSpecificLinksGenerator</mainClass>
  <args>
    <arg>master</arg>
    <arg>./masterLLfile.ttl</arg>
  </args>
</launcher>
```

the masterLLfile.ttl is the output file ,

i run it using the command

```
mvn scala:run -Dlauncher=GenerateLangLinksMasterFile
```

it's executed correctly , but i usually don't find the output file. but when i run the code from intellij without maven with the same arguments it appears in the path of the cmd

what's the default path that maven works in , how should i adapt it to appear in the cmd path ?

Comment: If `scala:run` doesn't mess with the current directory, I think it should be the root of your maven project (where `pom.xml` is).